# Book about a girl who turns into a cat

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading this book  back in 5th or 6th grade (I'm in 9th now), about a girl who moves into a new house with her mom and sister (maybe dad too; I can't remember); but her sister goes missing, and this cat gives her powers to turn into a cat, I think. It goes through a lot about her figuring out how to use her powers, and then she has to go save her sister.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds a bit like *Claws*, a 2012 YA novel by by [Mike and Rachel Grinti](http://www.grinti.com/books).

[image: US cover of Claws]

The blurb on their site reads:

> In a contemporary fairytale as irresistible as catnip, one girl discovers that some magic cuts deep...
>
> Emma's sister is missing. Her parents have spent all their savings on the search. And now the family has no choice but to live in a ramshackle trailer park on the edge of the forest, next door to down-and-out harpies, hags, and trolls. Emma wonders if she'll ever see Helena, and if she'll ever feel happy, again.
>
> Then she makes a friend.
>
> A smooth-talking, dirty-furred cat named Jack. He's got a razor-sharp plan to rescue Emma's sister. He just wants one small favor in return...

I haven't read it myself, but have scanned through it when my eldest read it. If I recall correctly, she doesn't turn into a cat, but rather gains the ability to control them.

Another thing noticeable is that the book contains excerpts from a site called *CragWiki.org*; a sort of Wikipedia of magic.

It has [over 90 reviews on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13069014-claws), most favourable.